# How can I manully release the memory which is allocated by auto release pool

Tags: ios

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = nil;
data = [prefs dataForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:KEY_STR, index]];
```

the NSData actually has 1.5M size, can I release the memory, as soon as I done with data?

Comment: Are you sure you really want to be storing 1.5mb of data in NSUserDefaults? That doesn't seem to be in the spirit of what NSUserDefaults is designed for, and the documentation recommends against it. You could store the data in an external file and reference it in a preference setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to create your own NSAutoreleasePool for this operation:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
// Your code here
[pool drain];
```

But unless you have a good reason to, you should know that as soon as you're done handling the event you're handling and the app returns back to the main run loop, the default autorelease pool will drain and your memory will be released.  So I wouldn't worry about it unless you think there's a good reason to.

Comment: I agree with this strongly (though you might prefer `[pool drain]` for style reasons); the only time I've had cause to manage autorelease pools manually is when I leave a large amount of data in the pool during each iteration of a loop, so as otherwise to create a huge peak memory bottleneck.

Comment: For ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) use the @autorelease compiler directive.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to stop you creating an object and releasing it within an autorelease pool (the autorelease pool is only responsible for releasing *autoreleased* objects which were created within it)

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] init]
[array release]

[pool release];
```

Is perfectly fine. In fact given the main run loop has its own autorelease pool and is periodically draining it, you are inevitably in this situation. This does not apply if you are using ARC.

I would also like to agree with stevex that storing megabytes into NSUserDefaults is wrong and will get you in trouble with iCloud. Write the data to a file.